# How to populate ktor server from another REST api?

Tags: rest, backend, ktor

I need to use an 3rd party rest api for my android app but this api requires me to use my own backend server.

So when i made a request from my app request will go to my ktor server and server should get data from another 3rd party api, how can i do that and what kinda structure should i use?

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer using [ktor-client](https://ktor.io/docs/getting-started-ktor-client.html) for this purposes, It is flexible, configurable and official package of ktor. I highly recommend it to you. Check the link.